Azure & ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - get images from blob storage
I have azure blob storage to store images for an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application running on AppService and I need best way to store images for different galleries.
I have definition in database like ImageName | Gallery_Id for example
and I will run some Ajax to get data from database by Gallery_Id
Now I have all image names (prox 150-250 images per gallery), but I need best and fastest way to render then on frontend and have like static function on backend that will retrieve them 1 by 1 from Azure blob seems little bit slow and so complicated.
public static string GetImagesFromBlob(string name)
{
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("");

    blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);

    List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();

    foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
    {
        if (blob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.Block)
            allBlobs.Add(blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name).Uri);
    }

    return "";
}

Actually I don't want to use SAS keys.
Is there any option to use already authenticated user on app and use image tag without SAS key?

The choice is up to you, really: either stream your content directly from your backend web app (and your app will be authenticated with your storage account), or provide URI's to your images, where the browser pulls them down (which requires either public-access images or SAS-based links). There's no right answer to this. Just note that with the first solution (streaming from your app), all bandwidth will go through your app, whereas the second solution (linking) will have bandwidth going from Azure Storage directly.

Any particular reason you don't want to use SAS keys? They're pretty easy to generate; just a single line of C#. And as the above commenter says, it avoids the bandwidth going through your App Service... Blob is a much cheaper way to serve.


is there any option to use already authenticated user on app and use image tag without SAS key?

Yes, you can use Microsoft Azure AD to authenticate users in your MVC application and then use the Azure Blob Storage SDK to access the storage account.
Create an app registration in the portal and fetch the client ID, tenant ID, and client secret from the app. Assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the storage account to access Azure Blob Storage.
Here is the code to get the list of blob names with ClientSecretCredential using .NET.
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string tenantId = "your-tenant-id";
            string clientId = "your-client-id";
            string clientSecret = "your-client-secret";
            string accountName = "your-account-name";
            string containerName = "your-container-name";

            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), credential); 
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            foreach (var blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobs())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
imp.png
sample3.txt
sample345.txt
test.xlsx

But I agree with David Makogon's comment,
Backend app:

If you decide to stream the content directly from your backend web app, you can use theAzure Blob Storage SDK to access your storage account and retrieve the images.
This method lets you authenticate users and manage access to the images. However, be aware that all data traffic will pass through your app, which might affect its performance. (which can increase the response time and reduce the throughput of your app).

SAS token:

If you choose to provide URIs for your images, the browser will fetch them directly from Azure Storage, which can reduce the response time and increase the throughput of your app.
However, you'll need to either make the images public or use SAS-based links to control access to them.

As David mentioned, the choice depends on your requirements. If you need to control access to the images and can handle the performance impact, streaming the content directly from your backend web app might be the best option. If performance is your priority and you're okay with making the images public or using SAS-based links, then providing URIs to the images might be the better choice.
Reference:
Authorize access to blobs using Microsoft Entra ID - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
